# Installation of ns-3

Tags: software-installation

Friends,
           I want to install ns-3 on my system please tell me from the beginning all the commands as well as provide me useful links also.
               Waiting for your favourable reply....

Answer (score 1):

NS3 is in [Main Ubuntu Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ns3)

You can simply install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install ns3
```